# Redirecting mysql output to prompt using shell

Tags: mysql, shell, output

I'm writing a shell code to automaticaly run multiple sql queries in multiple databases. My code is working well, but beside "select" queries, all other queries aren't displaying anything in the prompt while executing. How could I force query outputs to redirect to prompt?

That's some of my code:

```
      for x in "${db[@]}"
            do
                    found=0
                    for enreg in `cat /home/dbfile.csv`
                    do
                            #extracting database data from csv
                            DBNAME=`echo $enreg | awk -F";" '{ print $4 }'`

                            if [ $x = $DBNAME ]
                            then
                                    PASS=`echo $enreg | awk -F";" '{ print $2 }'`
                                    HOST=`echo $enreg | awk -F";" '{ print $3 }'`
                                    USERNAME=`echo $enreg | awk -F";" '{ print $1 }'`
                                    # Running queries in database $DBNAME
                                    for y in "${req[@]}"
                                    do
                                            echo "
                                            "
                                            mysql -u $USERNAME -p$PASS -h $HOST $DBNAME -e "$y"
                                            echo "
                                            "
                                    done
                                    found=1
                                    break
                            fi
                    done
                    if [ $found -eq 0 ]
                    then
                            echo "Database $x doesn't exist"
                    fi
            done
```

Comment: Are you just looking for the output to be more verbose so you can see what's going on? Have you considered using `mysql -v` for verbose mode (or maybe `-v -v` for more)?

Comment: Hello, I tried the mysql -v -v and it solved my problem. Thanks alot.